# Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in google places api

Tags: php, google-places-api

I'm trying to loop through a json response using PHP but I got this error :
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in line 45
here is the line : `echo $my_value->website;`
here is my full code :

```
$place = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJjSse9T9644kRo9eQsaidHMQ&key=[my key]');

$place_details = json_decode($place);
echo'<table id="table2" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">';
echo'<thead>';
echo '<tr>';`
echo '<th>Website</th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';`
echo '<tbody>';
foreach ($place_details->result as $my_value)
{ 
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>';
echo $my_value->website;
echo '</td>';
}
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: the error message is telling you that `$my_value` is not an object, so it doesn't have a property of `->website`. Do a `var_dump($place_details->result);` or `var_dump($place_details)` to see what your actual structure is.

Answer (score 0):

There's only **one** `website` per `result`, based on that, you can use:

```
$place = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJjSse9T9644kRo9eQsaidHMQ&key=AIzaSyDLBcG7vbaj4HmsE6gwSnNDCD0yHUNb9y4');
$place_details = json_decode($place, true);
echo $place_details['result']['website'];
# https://www.bmc.org/
```